# python vlookup: for each tab among 2 excel sheets

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python hence a little stuck in a code.

I have 2 excel sheets:

sheet1(workbook1):
Tab(worksheet) name = yogurt

[image]

sheet2(workbook2): 
Tab(worksheet) name = yogurt

[image]

each sheet has multiple tabs, similar data.
I need to copy the "state" from sheet1 to sheet2 (in the same column).
and it should run in a loop (each row and each worksheet).
I cant use merge because that will create duplicate columns.

something that I have done thanks to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRELNmDpaks :

```
wb1 = pd.ExcelFile(store_file1)
sn1 = wb1.sheet_names
wb2 = pd.ExcelFile(store_file2)
sn2 = wb2.sheet_names


for x in sn1 and y in sn2:
    if (x != 'hiddensheet' and x == y):
        df1 = sn1.parse(x) and df2 = sn2.parse(y)
        del df2['Enable Status']
        df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1[['SPIN ID', 'Enable Status']], on='SPIN ID', how='left')
        print(df3)
```

obviously, it is not working. :(

If anyone can help me with the function that I should use to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by making a dictionary at ID level in sheet1, and then calling that dictionary in sheet2 with respect to ID